# Computing the limit of $ \lim_{x\to\infty} \left( \frac{x^2+x+1}{3x^2+2x+1} \right) ^{\left( \frac{3x^2+x}{x-2} \right)} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> Computing the limit of $$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \left( \frac{x^2+x+1}{3x^2+2x+1} \right) ^{\left( \frac{3x^2+x}{x-2} \right)} $$

In this question I was able to deduce that the base function $$\left( \frac{x^2+x+1}{3x^2+2x+1} \right) \to 1/3\,\,,\,\,as\,\,x\to\infty $$

But for the power function we have $${\left( \frac{3x^2+x}{x-2} \right)}\to\infty$$ which implies it doesn't exist in $\mathbb R$

so I'm not sure how can we go about solving this case, though the answer seems to be 0.

I've gone through this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739133/limit-rule-lim-fxgx) which addresses how to deal with cases where we have $ \lim_{x\to c} f(x)^{g(x)} $ but I'm not sure how can it be applied in this case where $ \lim_{x\to \infty} {g(x)} =\infty $.

I also considered taking a log and then computing limits, but for that i guess we need limit to be greater than and
$ \lim_{x\to \infty} {g(x)} $ to be a real no.

I'm looking for a bit rigorous solution

Comment: base $f(x)\to \frac{1}{3}=3^{-1}$ and exponent $g(x)\to\infty$, then $f(x)^{g(x)}\to 3^{-\infty}=0$

Comment: @alexjo but how do you get that answer rigorously?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the definition of the limit here to do some more explicit ugly estimations. Assuming these are indeed the limits, you know that for any $M>1$, there exists some $x_M>0$ such that

$$  0<\frac{x^2+x+1}{3x^2+2x+1} <\frac{1}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad  \frac{3x^2+x}{x-2}>M  $$

for any $x>x_M$. Then you can say that

$$ 0 \leq \left( \frac{x^2+x+1}{3x^2+2x+1} \right) ^{\left( \frac{3x^2+x}{x-2} \right)} \leq \frac{1}{2^M} $$

for all $x>x_M$.

Comment: How did you bound the base function by 1/2?

Comment: Well you said the base function converges to a $1/3$. In particular, from some point onward it should be smaller than a half, or with distance at most $1/6$ from the limit.